# Travelling alone to Schengen countries with EU Family Residence Card

Tags: schengen

I am a non-EU national based in Norway. I hold a valid Norwegian Residence Card for family members of EU nationals. My wife is Latvian.

My question - would it be possible for me to travel to another Schengen country by air ALONE on my Norway residence permit.  Or do i need to be accompanied by my EU national spouse.

I have been reading on websites that it is a rule that non eu nationals have to be accompanied by their EU family members during travel to  schengen countries.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Norway is in Schengen!

Comment: @Sebastian yes it is, but as Henning Makholm's answer notes, there is a good deal of confusion about this because the free movement directive does not apply when the non-EU family member is traveling alone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sources of travel rights involved:

1. Those you have because you're a family member of a union citizen.
2. Those you have because *you hold a residence permit* from a Schengen country.

The rights from part (1) generally depend on you accompanying or joining the union citizen.

The rights from part (2) don't. You may have your residence permit *because* you're a family member, but a residence permit is still a residence permit, and gives you the same rights other residence permit do.

Part of the rights from part (2) is to make short trips *within the Schengen area* up to 90 days of every 180. Since this is triggered purely by having a residence permit, you do not need to accompany your wife to use that.

For comparison, if you want to go to an EU state that is *not* in Schengen, such as Ireland, you'd need to depend on the rights that are only triggered by accompanying or joining a union citizen. (Due to your Article 10 residence card they may not require a *visa* from you, but as far as I understand the directive they could still decide not to let you in when you're traveling alone, same as they can refuse entry to any visa-free national who arrives at the border).

Comment: With regard to the last paragraph, as far as I know there is no country that accepts an article 10 card in lieu of a visa when the bearer of the card is not traveling with or joining the family member.